# ffmpeg thumbnailor with timecode in filename

Tags: thumbnails

i have many videofiles and i want to make one thumbnails every 20 seconds.
This is what i have now:

```
for %%a in ("*.*") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -f image2 -vf fps=1/20 "index\%%~na_IMG-%%05d.jpg"
```

now i want to give the thumbnails a name with the timecode like this:

> VHS-0001_TC-00:00:00_IMG-001.jpg
>
> VHS-0001_TC-00:00:20_IMG-002.jpg
>
> VHS-0001_TC-00:00:40_IMG-003.jpg
>
> VHS-0001_TC-00:01:00_IMG-004.jpg

I am googling now for many hours but i can not found anything to create
a filename like this.

Have anyone an idear?

Thx a lot for your help and greating from Vienna

Stefan

Comment: similar question. seem like future not implemented. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544816/ffmpeg-filename-output-format

Comment: but you can draw timecode directly to image with `drawtext`